# How fill iframe inside div?

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, css-tables

I am trying to display an iframe in a `div[display=table-cell]` with 100% height, but code that don't work. That work only if I give fixed height to parent div, but contact-form's height must be dynamic and always `#contact-map` height must be like `#contact-form` height. What am I doing wrong? How to fill iframe inside `#contact-map`?

```css
textarea {
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 250px;
}
.contact {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 543px;
    display: table;
}

#contact-map {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

#contact-form {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
    <div id="contact-form">
        <p id="contact-street">text-text</p>
      <p id="contact-emailto">text-text</p>
      <p id="contact-telephone">123123</p>
      <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact_message"></textarea>
      </div>
    <div id="contact-map">
        <iframe src="http://google.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply height : 100% to all parent items (all the way up to html & body if needed).

since it is hard to see the way the iframe looks, i just gave it a red background.

The alternative would be to use Flexbox, which isn't supported properly on all browsers yet.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

textarea {
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 250px;
}
.contact {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 543px;
    display: table;
    height:100%;
}


#contact-map {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

#contact-form {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 43%;
    height:100%;
}

iframe
{
   background-color:red;
   height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
    <div id="contact-form">
        <p id="contact-street">text-text</p>
      <p id="contact-emailto">text-text</p>
      <p id="contact-telephone">123123</p>
      <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact_message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-map">
        <iframe style="background-color:red" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working good, check this example

it was happened because you only gave min-height to .contact class

try to give height also like this

```
.contact {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 543px;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this will helps you

```css
textarea {
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 250px;
}
.contact {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 543px;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#contact-map {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

#contact-form {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 43%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
    <div id="contact-form">
        <p id="contact-street">text-text</p>
      <p id="contact-emailto">text-text</p>
      <p id="contact-telephone">123123</p>
      <textarea name="contact_message" id="contact_message"></textarea>
      </div>
    <div id="contact-map">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A6XUVjK9W4o" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is there a youtube video in there?

Comment: @TimothyGroote when you try to add `https://www.google.com` than it will fire this error `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Comment: the same happens with the youtube video ;)

Comment: yeah about that, it puts the youtube video player in the iframe (which then fails because of cross origin requests. doesn't matter), but it doesn't scale the iframe height up along with the other table cell.

Comment: Maybe because of the language barrier, I can not explain what I can not realize. I will show on the original. Check http://dropmefiles.com/FsLWO

Comment: Does not work. iframe doesn't fill #contact-map and display with white space bottom